# Merge array values, alternating

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to merge arrays but would like to alternate the order.

```
$combined = array_merge($vars,$mods);
```

gives me: one,two,three,1,2,3...

I'd like: one,1,two,2,three,3...

is there a way to do this?

Comment: What if the arrays have different numbers of items? Just push all the extra ones from the larger array onto the end of the result?

Comment: In my form both form the fields are set up so that for every entry in the $vars array there is an equivalent entry in the $mods array. Both will always have an equal number of values.

Comment: What is your array in the first place? Please provide more context.

Comment: Seems easy enough to infer from the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop and refer to the index of each of the arrays you're combining.

```
$l = count($vars);
for ($i=0; $i < $l; $i++) {
    $combined[] = $vars[$i];
    $combined[] = $mods[$i];
}
```

In each iteration of the loop, you'll append one item from each of the original arrays. This will achieve the alternating effect.

---

As Steve pointed out, this can be done more simply using `foreach`:

```
foreach ($vars as $i => $value) {
    $combined[] = $value;
    $combined[] = $mods[$i];
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest building it as a function so you can use it in multiple places if needed.

Comment: If the keys are always sequential in both arrays you can replace the first two lines with `foreach($vars as $i => $value) {`