# How can I merge two associative arrays and preserve the global order of the entries?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have two arrays like this:

```
$arr1 = ['a' => '1','b' => 2];
$arr2 = ['h' => 'c','j' => '3'];
```

And I want to merge them to this result:

```
$newArr = ['a' => '1','h'=>'c','b'=>2,'j' => '3'];
```

That means I want to merge them so that the global order of the entries is the same as in the source arrays. In other words, zip and flatten.

`array_merge` does not do this. Is there any solution?

Comment: [Transpose and flatten multiple rows of array data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43618598/2943403), [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899735/merge-array-values-alternating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39899735/2943403), [Merge two arrays alternatively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17638953/2943403), [PHP best solution to merge array in alternate order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57078697/2943403), [Merge every other array php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8194327/2943403), ...

Comment: [Merge two flat indexed arrays of equal size so that values are pushed into the result in an alternating fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11827451/2943403)

Comment: What does this have to do with Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this solution will only work if the two arrays have the same length:

```
$arr1 = [ 'a' => '1', 'b' => 2 ];
$arr2 = [ 'h' => 'c', 'j' => '3' ];

$count = count($arr1);
$keys1 = array_keys($arr1);
$keys2 = array_keys($arr2);

$result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $key1 = $keys1[$i];
  $result[$key1] = $arr1[$key1];
  $key2 = $keys2[$i];
  $result[$key2] = $arr2[$key2];
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [h] => c
    [b] => 2
    [j] => 3
)
```

Edited based on *mickmackusa*'s comment below.

Comment: Now it more closely resembles one if my snippets.

Comment: No offense, but what is the purpose of this comment in light of the fact that you posted your answer two hours after mine?

Comment: The reasons that factor into how late my answer was: 1. I always search for duplicates before posting 2. The page was closed when I first read it. 3.  I do not play the fastest gun in the west game -- I post late answers when I have unique, superior advice to add to a page. 4. I was consulting one of the people who closed the page as unclear -- I wanted to hear their rationale for the closure. 5. I test all my code in a sandbox before I post because I want every one of my answers to be provably correct, if not perfect.

Comment: That is not an answer to my question, but I'll leave it here...

Answer (score 3):

First is a solution that will consume the input arrays in a loop while building the new structure.  You can always cache separate copies of the input if you need them elsewhere.

All solutions below will work even if the two arrays have different lengths -- any remaining elements will be appended to the end of the result array after the loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CCf0P))

```
$result = [];
while ($arr1 && $arr2) {
    $result += array_splice($arr1, 0, 1)
        + array_splice($arr2, 0, 1);
}
$result += $arr1 + $arr2;
var_export($result);
```

---

Another way without consuming the input arrays is to build lookup arrays:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AIo5i))

```
$max = max(count($arr1), count($arr2));
$keys1 = array_keys($arr1);
$keys2 = array_keys($arr2);

$result = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < $max; ++$x) {
    if (isset($keys1[$x])) {
        $result[$keys1[$x]] = $arr1[$keys1[$x]];
    }
    if (isset($keys2[$x])) {
        $result[$keys2[$x]] = $arr2[$keys2[$x]];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

---

Or you could use `array_slice()` to isolate one element at a time from each array without damaging the input arrays, nor generating warnings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tNcU3))

```
$result = [];
for ($i = 0, $count = count($arr1); $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $result += array_slice($arr1, $i, 1)
        + array_slice($arr2, $i, 1);
}
$result += $arr1 + $arr2;
```

Comment: Hmm... seems I've been down a similar path before.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69114863/2943403

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_merge() or array_merge_recursive().

Merges the elements of one or more arrays such that the values of one array are appended to the end of the previous one. The result of the function is a new array.
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php

The array_merge_recursive() function merges the elements of two or more arrays in such a way that the values ​​of one array are appended to the end of the other. Returns the resulting array.

If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values ​​of those keys are merged into an array, and this is done recursively, so that if one of the values ​​is an array, then the function merges it with the corresponding value in the other array. However, if the arrays have the same numeric keys, each successive value will not replace the original value, but will be added to the end of the array.
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_merge function,which uses to merge two or more arrays into single array.

```
$arr1 = ['a' => '1','b' => 2];
$arr2 = ['h' => 'c','j' => '3'];
$result=array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
var_dump($result);
//output:- array(4) { ["a"]=> string(1) "1" ["b"]=> int(2) ["h"]=> string(1) "c" ["j"]=> string(1) "3" }
```

Comment: This does not fulfil the requirement, please read the question carefully.